# Query builder not respecting $fillable

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

When I call `update()` using the following code it works well and respects `$fillable`:

```
$lead = Lead::findOrFail($id);
$lead->update(request()->all());
```

However, when I call `update()` using the following code it is not respecting `$fillable` at all:

```
$lead = Lead::whereRaw('json_extract(lower(data), "$.email") = lower(?)', request()->input('email'));
$lead->update(request()->all());
```

Now I can only assume this is related to the query builder. How do I get the 2nd bit of code to respect `$fillable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first query, you use `findOrFail()` which always returns a model.

In your second query your `whereRaw()` function doesn't know if one or more rows matches these conditions, so it returns a Collection that may have any number of elements.

If you append `->firstOrFail()` to your second query, it will take the first result, or fail if no results are found.